# BootStrap grid not working, col-XX-X in one row always shwing multi-row

Tags: row, col, grip

[image: my screen resolution is 1280*1024]I am beginner of bootstrap, just using "Starter template" to see grid result, but I can't see three column of "col-lg-4" showing in one row, attached code, I don't see any script error, 
and my display resolution 1280 * 1024 .please help. thanks a lot.

[suppose in one row, but in 3 row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG5l3.png)

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">11111</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">22222</div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">33333</div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your screen size is greater than 1200px?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should give exactly 4 grids to each div exactly as you have specified it to do if your screen size is greater than `1200px`. In bootstrap-3 that you are using, `lg` specifies screen that is greater than or equal to `1200px`. So your screen size falls in this category. Consider your piece of code below -

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">11111</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">22222</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="border: 1px solid red;">33333</div>

</div>
```

- You have used `<div class="col-lg-4"`. What this specifies is, use 4 grids of bootstrap grid system when the screen size is `lg` and 12 grids in all other case (which is the default if not specified for other screen sizes).

You can check your screen resolution from [here](http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/). Make sure if its greater than 1200px. You can run the program from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fa9kvz64/). You will see than as long as the screen size remains >= 1200px, each divs get 4 grids and remain on the same row.

---

If you want 3 grids for each div and you are not getting it with `col-lg-4`, you should probably try `col-md-4`, which will place all divs on the same row even on a medium size screen(laptop screens : 992px - 1200px) and it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I checked my resolution, is 1280*1024, I think 1280px is the one greater then 1200px, and I run the code from the link as well, it's still showing 3 rows, not in same one row. and I try "col-md-4" instead "col-lg-4", it's working perfect all 3 in one row.